# Multiple "AND" conditions in a while loop c#

Tags: c#

Newbie and i´ve browsed for answers for a while but can´t seem to get it to work. I have a loop with two int variables that increase with different amount each loop depending on their set value before the loop starts. I want the loop to break and print the value of both ints when both of them have exceeded a set value. The problem i keep getting is that it seems like as soon as the first condition in both the "if" conditions and "while" conditions are met the  So grateful if anyone could point out where I´m going wrong. Maybe this isn´t the best way to create this function?

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Please enter value1");
string strValue1 = Console.ReadLine();
int value1 = Convert.ToInt32(strValue1);
int value2 = 20;
do
{

    if (value1 < 50 || value2 < 50)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("increase value 2 a little");
        value2 = value2 + 10;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("increase value 2 a lot");
        value2 = value2 + 30;
    }
    value1++;
}

while ((value2 < 200) && (value1 < 60));
Console.WriteLine("value1 is " + value1);
Console.WriteLine("value2 is " + value2);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Yes, you've said that the loop should only continue while `value2` is less than 200 *and* `value1` is less than 60. Perhaps you meant *or* instead of *and*?

Comment: Try debugging this, and you will find out.... (If you do not know hot to debug, see: [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop condition tests *both* variables to be less than a certain threshold. As soon as one variable exceeds the threshold, the condition is no longer true. This is different from testing if both variables are above a certain threshold.

If you want the loop to exit only when both variables exceed the threshold, change the condition to use `||` (i.e. or): `while (value2 < 200 || value1 < 60)`. Your condition tests the opposite ("both variables must be less"); but could be adapted to match your verbal description more closly: `while (!(value2 >= 200 && value >= 60))`

As a general rule of thumb: `!(a && b)` is equivalent to `!a || !b`. Same for `!(a || b)` is equivalent to `!a && !b`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ve spent most of the day with trial and error mixed with pulling my hair off. I’ll try this tomorrow. I’m so grateful.

Comment: It solved my problem. Thank you once again. Since new I´ll ask a question on etiquette. When writing a comment i get a little hint not to write thank you or like etc. I take it as it´s the preferred behavior when received help just to be silent? No thank you for the help or acknowledgement that the help worked?